# In Android Studio, text does not appear on top of an image

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I'm doing a small project on Android Studio, and I've put a picture as a dark blue background.
I inserted white text on top of this dark blue figure, but the white color in the letters still doesn't show.
The Graphical Interface. See that I put the color white, but it still doesn't show up.
Please, check out:

Please, can anyone help to
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTtiS.png

Source-code in the XML:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6AIU.png

Please, what to do to the white text appear on the top of the image in Android Studio?

Whole XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:color="@color/white"
        android:foreground="@drawable/home_bg"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Encontre o seu próximo destino!"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.32"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.233" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="176dp"
            android:layout_height="41dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
            android:text="Procurar Destinos"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.324"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.742" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please add your whole xml layout?

Comment: Sure! I wrote this now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think the problem is that you've set the foreground of the constraint layout instead of the background.

Try this:

```xml
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:color="@color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/home_bg"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much :)